# Split string by space in ZSH

Tags: zsh

Given `file.txt`:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

This works in `bash`:

```
while IFS=' ' read -a args; do
  echo "${args[0]}"
done < file.txt
```

To produce

```
first
second
third
```

That is to say, we were able to read the file line by line, and on each one we split the line further into an array using space as a delimiter. But in `zsh`, the result is an error: `read: bad option: -a`.

How can we achieve in `zsh` the same as in `bash`? I’ve tried several solutions, but I was never able to **split a string into an array using spaces as the delimiter**.

Comment: Can you use the `cut` binary? It is not a shell built-in, but it will do what you want via `cut -d ' ' -f 1 file.txt`.

Comment: @JeremyDover It would work for this case, but I want something more robust, hence asking for an array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [`man zshbuiltins`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins), zsh's read uses `-A` instead.

```
read [ -rszpqAclneE ] [ -t [ num ] ] [ -k [ num ] ] [ -d delim ]
     [ -u n ] [ name[?prompt] ] [ name ...  ]
...
       -A     The  first  name  is taken as the name of an array
              and all words are assigned to it.
```

Hence the command is

```
while IFS=' ' read -A args; do
  echo "${args[1]}"
done < file.txt
```

N.B. by default, zsh array numbering begins with `1`, whereas bash's begins with `0`.

```
$ man zshparam
...
Array Subscripts
...
The elements are numbered  beginning  with  1, unless the
KSH_ARRAYS option is set in which case they are numbered from zero.
```

Comment: You are correct. I had tried `-A` but it did not seem to be working. It was a combination of the 1-based index plus the differences in slicing that were tripping me up.